# Incomplete download using requests in Python

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis

I'm following an online project where we predict the air quality index. In order to do that, we need to get the data first, which we are downloading from a website. Here is the source code provided by the author:

```
import os
import time
import requests
import sys

def retrieve_html():
    for year in range(2013,2019):
        for month in range(1,13):
            if(month<10):
                url='http://en.tutiempo.net/climate/0{}-{}/ws-421820.html'.format(month
                                                                          ,year)
            else:
                url='http://en.tutiempo.net/climate/{}-{}/ws-421820.html'.format(month
                                                                          ,year)
            texts=requests.get(url)
            text_utf=texts.text.encode('utf=8')
            
            if not os.path.exists("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year)):
                os.makedirs("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year))
            with open("Data/Html_Data/{}/{}.html".format(year,month),"wb") as output:
                output.write(text_utf)
            
        sys.stdout.flush()
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    start_time=time.time()
    retrieve_html()
    stop_time=time.time()
    print("Time taken {}".format(stop_time-start_time))
```

This works perfectly fine. Now, I tried writing the same code on my own. Here is my code:

```
import os
import time
import requests
import sys


def retrieve_html():
    for year in range(2013,2019):
        for month in range(1,13):
            if(month<10):
                url='http://en.tutiempo.net/climate/0{}-{}/ws-421820.html'.format(month, year)
            else:
                url='http://en.tutiempo.net/climate/{}-{}/ws-421820.html'.format(month, year)
        
        texts=requests.get(url)
        text_utf=texts.text.encode("utf=8")
        
        if not os.path.exists("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year)):
            os.makedirs("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year))
        
        with open("Data/Html_Data/{}/{}.html".format(year,month),"wb") as output:
            output.write(text_utf)
            
    sys.stdout.flush()
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    start_time=time.time()
    retrieve_html()
    stop_time=time.time()
    print("Time taken: {}".format(stop_time-start_time))
```

But whenever I run this script, only the data from the 12th month is getting downloaded and the rest of the data from the other months aren't getting downloaded. I checked using the code provided by the author and it is working perfectly fine, although my code is exactly the same as his. This is driving me crazy. Can anyone please point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Your code is not the same.  You only have four lines of code indented underneath the `for month in range(1,13)` loop, and the author has ten lines.

Comment: Thank you! I'm moving over from Java, so I completely forgot about the indentations in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not exactly the same, there are different indentations:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should indent this:

```
        texts=requests.get(url)
        text_utf=texts.text.encode("utf=8")
        
        if not os.path.exists("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year)):
            os.makedirs("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year))
        
        with open("Data/Html_Data/{}/{}.html".format(year,month),"wb") as output:
            output.write(text_utf)
```

Answer (score 1):

Code is correct only there is indentation problem. The following code should be in the inner for loop

```
texts=requests.get(url)
text_utf=texts.text.encode("utf=8")
        
if not os.path.exists("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year)):
   os.makedirs("Data/Html_Data/{}".format(year))
        
   with open("Data/Html_Data/{}/{}.html".format(year,month),"wb") as output:
        output.write(text_utf)
```

And the following code should be in the outer for loop

```
sys.stdout.flush()
```